# CakePHP 2.x : how do I order a model from the values in another?

Tags: cakephp, model, pagination, associations

This is the scenario: I have a `Posts` Model and each post has a `Meta` attached through `$hasMany`. The Meta model contains a view counter, a download counter, etc.

This is done this way to avoid updating the Post every time a user visits a post, and because I'll have another index where the most recently modified posts will reside, so changing a Post on every visit defeats the purpose of the "recently modified" index so the `views` and `downloads` are saved in Meta.

**How can I order the Posts index view with pagination using the data from the Meta model like downloads so the Posts are sorted by downloads?**

I hope that's clear enough, if you need more data please leave a comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare the paginate settings, like this

```
   $this -> paginate = array(
            'limit' => 3, // your desired limitation
            'contain' => array('Meta'),
            'fields' => array(
                'Post.title',
                'Post.date_published',
                ...,
                'Meta.downloads',
                'Meta.views'
            ),
            'order' => 'Meta.downloads {ASC|DESC}'
        );
```

Then you can paginate like this:

```
$this -> set('posts', $this -> paginate('Post'));
```

assuming your Models are called Post and Meta.

**EDIT**
In order for this to work (the contain key in the paginate array), you need to add the Containable behavior to the Meta model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Comment: It didn't work, I get a database error:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Meta.downloads' in 'field list'`

Comment: Okay, I edited the above answer. Please try it with the Containable behavior included (AND the 'contain' key in the paginate array.

Comment: You can't use order on `Meta` model in this case because cake doesn't do joins for 1:n or n:n relations. You either have to use an ad-hoc joins or unbind/bind `Meta` as a `hasOne`.